# How to redirect terminal output with the formatting and color in Mac (Ventura)?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, shell

I am running huge volumes of tests and the output is displayed on terminal, I would however like it to be stored to be be read, searched for further use. Is there a wat to have it redirect with color.
I can always copy to any rich text editor/Word/Google Docs but redirecting it directly to a file is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy, standard, or built-in way to do what you're looking for.

Some command-line tools (including terminal-based apps) look at what kind of terminal your current terminal emulator app claims to be, and if it claims to be some kind of color terminal (such as "xterm-color"), those command-line tools send the old terminal control codes that should cause that particular model of terminal to show the text in different colors. These terminal control codes are also called "escape codes" or "escape sequences" because they often begin with the "escape" character (ASCII 27, 0x1b).

The tools that do this are often smart enough to stop doing the terminal color codes when redirecting to a text file, because a text file is not a terminal, so the terminal color codes become meaningless when stored in a plain ASCII text file. It's also considered bad form to put the escape character, or any of the non-printable low-ASCII "control characters" (most of the ASCII values below 32) into a plain text file.

There's no standard way for plain text files to store color information. The closest thing might be the Rich Text Format (.rtf), but the traditional Unix command-line environment doesn't have RTF support integrated throughout; it only does plain text.

Your tool that outputs things in color in the terminal is almost certainly the thing that is choosing to omit color codes when outputting to a text file. Read its manual to see if it provides you an option to keep the embedded terminal color codes when redirecting to a text file. Then if you "cat" that text file to the same (emulated) model of color terminal, it might show in color. You might even be able to write a script to interpret those escape codes and convert them to RTF color sequences or something.

The reason the color is kept when you copy from the terminal and paste into a styled-text-capable word processor or other app is because your terminal emulator app is converting it on the fly to RTF (or whatever your OS's native styled text format is) when it copies it to the clipboard.